# Google Analytics DataSet Type (CRMint)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-analytics

I am novice to Google Analytics and I am using a tool called CRMint to import a custom audience to Google Analytics. A Data Scientist is using a model to predict if a user has more chances to buy a product than another. Right now, I have a `csv` file containing 2 columns `fullVisitorId` and `predictions`.

[image: csv]

On CRMint, I am using a job called "`GaDataImporter`" to import that CSV file into Google Analytics. As you can see on the picture bellow, I need to provide a `GA Dataset ID`.
[image]

I am currently trying to create a new DataSet from my Google Analytics dashboard but I am not sure about the `dataset type` and the `import bahavihor`. Anyone has some suggestions?
[image: datasettype][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fullVisitorId` is not an available dimension in Google Analytics (found only on BigQuery) so you cannot use it to link information to users in Google Analytics.

Rather you should use the `clientId` passed to Analytics as **custom dimension**, then use that as a key by importing the data as **Custom Data**.

(If you are novice to Google Analytics it is not something that can be explained in a post, anyway the process described is what you need)

Comment: Thank you Michele. Should I create a new custom dimension called `clientId`? Also in my Data Set schema, I have the possibility to use the  `userId ` as a key (not a custom dimension)

Comment: If you have that information you can use it and import with User Data.